# Jquery plug in to make do a drag and drop with complete features

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a website where the user can drag and drop objects : table, line, words, and images. Then the user can change the dropped objects' attributes, such as font style , color , resize its size and change border colors. Is there any JQuery plug in that similiar to what i'm doing ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a similar project, with drag and drop and also resize. You just need jquery UI, you can use the function inside: draggable, droppable and resizeable. It works well for me :)

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Draggable

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and also for the link =) I've checked the link and find out how to drag but didn't find the way to resize it. Would you mind to post how you set the div to be resizeable ? Thanks

Comment: Just refreshed the page and found your edited post. Now it works well. Thanks =)

Comment: @sathis Yuph, im sorry , im still new to this. Thanks for the fast reply =)